# What is the correct place for an adverb that modifies a predicate adjective?

Tags: adverbs

Which of the following is more correct?

1. When I speak, what I say is grammatically correct.

or

2. When I speak, what I say is correct grammatically.

Comment: Generally the first would be preferred, since `Modifier - Head` is the normal form for a non-verbal predicate: _He's a big boy ~ She's very tired._ But the second is grammatical, too; it just doesn't form a constituent with the adjective. Probably an adverb in that position would modify the entire verb phrase (including the auxiliary _be_) instead of just the predicate adjective.

Comment: Domain modifiers-of-adjectives doubtless have more mobility than emphasisers / scalar sufficiency markers etc (When I speak, what I say is absolutely correct / accurate enough / too blunt.) To say nothing of the negator _not_.

Comment: When I speak, what I say is correct, grammatically. The two are semantically the same thing if you use the comma. There is only a difference in stylistic meaning from intonation. Or how it is "read in the head".

Answer (score 2):

> Generally the first would be preferred, since Modifier - Head is the normal form for a non-verbal predicate: He's a big boy ~ She's very tired. But the second is grammatical, too; it just doesn't form a constituent with the adjective. Probably an adverb in that position would modify the entire verb phrase (including the auxiliary be) instead of just the predicate adjective. – John Lawler